# New Measure in Power BI which show count of raw_stnd_id for each raw_adm_appl_id where rn_desc = 1

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table as below, this below sample has only two raw_adm_appl_id, but the full table has many raw_adm_appl_id

[image: Sample Table]

I want to create a new measure using DAX which will count all the raw_stdnt_id's where rn_desc = 1 partitioned by raw_adm_appl_id. Means for each raw_adm_appl_id, it will take the row where the rn_desc = 1 and count total number of rows having run_desc = 1 over all the different raw_adm_appl_id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write a measure

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[raw_stdnt_id]), 'Table'[rn_desc] = 1)
```

Then write summarize function to get desired result

```
Table 2 = SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[raw_adm_appl_id], "stdnt_count", [Measure])
```

Comment: Hi Ashok, Thanks for your reply, your First step itself got me the correct value. I did not have to do the second step. To check if I get the correct value, I do it in sql and check if Power BI gives me the same value. Thanks